# Did Unity PlayerPrefs are Deleted While Updating My App in iOS

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an app in ios. It was developed in Unity 2018.3.7f1.Its working fine. I have an playerprefs in my app to identify how many levels are user played in my app. The problem is while updating my app  the level started from beginning. Its not started from where the user last played.

So my question is Did Playerprefs are deleted while updating my App?

How can i Avoid it?Where i can store playerprefs that it should get deleted while updating my App?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: **Most Possible yes.** That's the reason why you **should NOT** use `PlayerPrefs` for storing important functional stuff like game progress etc. **at all**! It is ment for storing **settings/preferences** (therefore it's name) like e.g. sound volume. Use something else for storing important data (external file etc)

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubt.  Where i can store the important information. For eg. i have to check how many levels user played.I have stored in Playerprefs. Now it is deleted. Where i can store the information?It should not get deleted. How can i do it.

Comment: As said write it to a file or database etc

Comment: Is it possible to store playerprefs in Application.Persistentdatapath without  be deleted..

Comment: Usually that should work and not be deleted. You should always test and confirm that though. If you want to go for absolutely sure the solution would always be a server and database. But yes local files are at least way more secure then PlayerPrefs.

Comment: check this  https://forum.unity.com/threads/playerprefs-deleted-after-ios-app-update.335669/